# Python read text files in numpy array when empty or single line

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading from text files with the code below:

```
import numpy as np
my_data = np.genfromtxt(resultsDirectory+'/Points.txt', delimiter=' ')
PointX = my_data[:,5]
PointY = my_data[:,11]
```

My input files are typically like this -

```
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 7 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 1 Result : FAIL Time : 0 Epsilon : 0.5
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 11 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 1 Result : FAIL Time : 2 Epsilon : 0.5
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 7 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 3 Result : FAIL Time : 2 Epsilon : 0.25
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 13 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 1 Result : FAIL Time : 7 Epsilon : 0.25
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 7 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 4 Result : FAIL Time : 8 Epsilon : 0.125
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 8 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 2 Result : FAIL Time : 1 Epsilon : 0.125
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 8 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 3 Result : FAIL Time : 3 Epsilon : 0.125
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 8 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 4 Result : FAIL Time : 6 Epsilon : 0.125
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 9 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 2 Result : FAIL Time : 6 Epsilon : 0.125
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 10 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 2 Result : FAIL Time : 5 Epsilon : 0.125
ParamA : 0 ParamB : 14 ParamC : 0 ParamD : 1 Result : FAIL Time : 6 Epsilon : 0.125
```

When I extract PointX from this I get

```
PointX = [7 11 7 13 7 8 8 8 9 10 14]
PointY = [1 1 3 1 4 2 3 4 2 2 1]
```

Now, sometimes my text files contain only a single line or are even empty.

For example, if the text file has only one line, the my_data array is like this -

```
[  nan   nan   0.    nan   nan   7.    nan   nan   0.    nan   nan   1.
   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan  0.    nan   nan   0.5]
```

In this case, `my_data.shape` returns `(21,)`.

However reading the array `PointX` or `PointY` gives me an error as `IndexError: invalid index`. I wanted `PointX=[7]` and `PointY=[1]`. Or if the text file is empty, it should be `PointX=[]` and `PointY=[]`.

How exactly should I solve this problem? Also I need my `PointX` and `PointY` to be an array in order not to break the code which is dependent on it.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what items you want to be in `PointX` and `PointY`. Are you wanting everything up to the 6th element to be in `PointX`, and everything up to the 12th element in `PointY`?

Comment: Would you provide an example of the data in your CSV file?

Comment: @Andy I wanted to read the value 7 and 1 in array PointX and PointY respectively. I have updated the problem description accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `genfromtxt` returns a 1D array if given a file with only one line, and returns a 2D array if given more than one line. You could handle the discrepancy by reshaping:

```
import numpy as np
my_data = np.genfromtxt('data', delimiter=' ')
if my_data.ndim == 1:
    my_data = my_data.reshape(1, -1)
PointX = my_data[:,5]
PointY = my_data[:,11]
print(PointX)
print(PointY)
```

yields

```
[ 7.]
[ 1.]
```

Comment: Perfect ! Just what I needed ! :)

Answer (score 2):

To handle empty files:

```
import numpy as np
try:
    my_data = np.genfromtxt('data_file', delimiter=' ')
    if my_data.ndim == 1:
        my_data = my_data.reshape(1, -1)
    PointX = my_data[:,5]
    PointY = my_data[:,11]
except IOError: # File is empty
    PointX = []
    PointY = []

print(PointX)
print(PointY)
```